# How to append a time zone in iOS?

Tags: ios, nsdate

I have a string MMddyyyy_HH:mm:ss... Need to apply EST to this time string and convert the string to NSDate.

The NSDate should be of EST time.

How to achieve this?

Comment: show some code please

Comment: What part do you need help with? Appending the string or using `NSDateFormatter` to convert the final string to an `NSDate`?

Comment: @rmaddy using NSDateFormatter to convert the final string in this MMddyyyy_HH:mm:ss format to EST date

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. There are a million existing questions on that topic to get you started.

Comment: NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMddyyyy_HH:mm:ss"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"]];
    NSDate *responseDate  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:responseTimeStamp];

This is what I have tried, but not seems to work.

Comment: Update your question with the code so we can read it.

Answer (score 1):

Use timeZone property of NSDateFormatter with which you will convert your string.